# How should a system get data from a remote third party data source?

Tags: web-services, sftp, remote-access

A vendor's remote system has data that one of our internal systems needs daily. Our system currently receives the data daily by the vendor's system pushing a CSV file via SFTP. The data is < 1KB in size.

We are considering using a pull via SFTP instead. The file "should" always be ready no later than a defined time (5 ET). So, one problem with this approach could be that our system may have to do some polling to eventually get the file.

How should a system get data from a remote third party data source? The vendor also provides a web service and subscription feed service. They will also consider other ideas for us to acquire the data.

Comment: You can't close a question with an open bounty? Why ever not? This question would appear to be both to broad, and also soliciting primarily opinion based answers.

Comment: As Andrew said in the comment above its an opinion based question but if you go with pulling data from CSV I would suggest you to look at ETL tools. 

SSIS (Integration Services) - Comes with SQL Server
Kettle - Open Source (http://etl-tools.info/en/pentaho/kettle-etl.htm)

Why to use ETL tool instead of hand coding it: 

http://www.informationweek.com/software/information-management/kimball-university-should-you-use-an-etl-tool/d/d-id/1066486?

You can have a retry count for your FTP task(connection retry) or you can also have a loop to try x times before failing.

Comment: You asked for alternatives without stating what exactly the problem you're solving. You've already got some working method, so what's wrong with it? You also didn't explain why you'll need polling if file should be ready after some time: then what's wrong about just coming after that time and pull it? Basic answer to you question would be: "A system should get data from remote source according to its exact requirements to the ideal acquiring process, or at least as close as possible to it." Determining the requirements is individual task for each specific case.

Comment: I would say there is an immediate and clear advantage to pulling vs receiving in such a scenario through the simple fact that it is the other party which would have to put resources into the uptime guarantee. Speaking from an operations point of view, this alone motivates the question as phrased regardless of other aspects.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming your system is unix-like*, and the other side has an open SSH server, I would add the public key of the user that your application runs under to the authorized_keys file in the remote side. After this, your application would be able to poll for the existence of an updated file by running

```
ssh username_at_remote_end@ip_address_of_remote stat -C %Z path_to_file
```

Which will output the seconds after the unix Epoch of the last change to the file (if found) or error (non-zero exit code) if file not found.

To actually retrieve the file (after checking that the time-stamp is within the last 24 hours), I would use

```
t=$(mktemp -d) && scp username_at_remote_end@ip_address_of_remote:path_to_file $t && echo $t
```

Which will copy it to a temporary directory under `/tmp`, readable only by the user that your application is running under, and will return the name of that folder.

All programming languages support running commands locally (in C, using `system()`; in Java, using a `Process`; ...). To keep things simple, each command would be added to a script file (say `poll.sh` and `retrieve.sh`). If the remote end changes, you only have to update & test the scripts. There are direct interfaces to `openssh`, but it is probably simpler to outsource all of that work to `bash` via scripts as seen above.

Comment: +1 for simplicity. There is no complicated logic in polling for a csv through sftp, I usually do it through a cron job every x minutes or whichever interval fits the usecase. One can add a simple check to see if the file has already been downloaded. Very low maint compared to SSIS and so on, as the required tools and logic are both simple to use and directly available through the shell.

Answer (score 0):

IF you have similar requirements for more that one case, you can consider using integration server (middleware) to implement this. There you can design a trigger which will invoke that particular pull after 5 ET.
If this is required for only one case, then ask your provider for webservice option. Where you can call his webservice after 5ET once a day by sending a soap request for data and he will return a soap response rather than csv. You can implement it very easily in your system. It will be more secured and efficient. You will have more control on data, transport and security.